# What is it meant by Console in windows programming?

Tags: c, windows, console, systems-programming

I've got a problem with windows consoles... In windows api, does a **console** always has to be a screen or a keyboard or can it be any character buffer or something like a text file ?

thanx

If I be more specific, **SetConsoleMode** fnction in windows api has a parameter called **hConsoleHandle** which has a flag called **ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT** that can be used to echo every character we read to the screen.. So I thought in windows system programming, Console means something more than it's normal meaning... So am I write and if so what is the true meaning..?

thanx again

Comment: Can you clarify the context of your question?  Knowing what you are trying to accomplish will help someone provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a "console" implies an application that has a text-based interface.

[Win32 Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console) on Wikipedia says that that label specifies a text mode program that runs under the Windows API, and would use, for example, a function like `WriteConsole` instead of `printf` or `cout`.

So, the console's the same, but the underlying library is different.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, the console is always a window that resembles the Command Prompt window. You can open and read and write from/to that thing in your windows program. It's not a buffer or a text file, but you can write a buffer or text file and then transfer that entity to the console.

[image: windows console]

Here are the C-language functions you can use when you address the console window:

```
_cgets, _cgetws, _cgets_s, _cgetws_s
 Read string from console

_cprintf, _cwprintf, _cprintf_s, _cprintf_s_l, _cwprintf_s, _cwprintf_s_l
 Write formatted data to console

_cputs
 Write string to console

_cscanf, _cwscanf, _cscanf_s, _cscanf_s_l, _cwscanf_s, _cwscanf_s_l
 Read formatted data from console

_getch, _getwch
 Read character from console

_getche, _getwche
 Read character from console and echo it

_inp
 Read one byte from specified I/O port

_inpd
 Read double word from specified I/O port

_inpw
 Read 2-byte word from specified I/O port

_kbhit
 Check for keystroke at console; use before attempting to read from console

_outp
 Write one byte to specified I/O port

_outpd
 Write double word to specified I/O port

_outpw
 Write word to specified I/O port

_putch, _putwch
 Write character to console

_ungetch, _ungetwch
 "Unget" last character read from console so it becomes next character read
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's well described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
Consoles manage input and output (I/O) for character-mode applications 
(applications that do not provide their own graphical user interface).
```

so you have your answer right there. As asked before, try to explain better your context, your objective and what is your idea, so maybe we can help you out more.